# Filling HTML Input Boxes That Were Created With Select2

Tags: jquery, vba, jquery-select2, browser-automation

I'm using Excel VBA to automate a web page.  The "Select" boxes and "Input" boxes were created by a jQuery platform called "Select2."

When the user clicks on a "Select box" (which appears as an input box) a dropdown box pops up asking the user to type in two characters.  I've discovered that you can add a valid data item into this box with this command by inserting the select box ID.

```
myDoc.parentWindow.execScript "$('#s2id_broomCloset').val('Swiffer - Model 2010').trigger('change')"
```

Most of the input boxes are like any other where you can change them with

```
myDoc.GetElementByID("broomCloset").value = "Swiffer"
```

However, there is one input box built with Select2 which involves a validation drop down list asking the user to type the first two characters and it lists employees whose last names start with those two characters.  Then the user is supposed to select the employee from the list.

This input box is tied to an "

[image]

I was able to use the advice of

I have tried everything I can think of to enter a valid response into this input box.  Here are a couple of failed attempts:

```
myDoc.GetElementByID("s2id_beanCounter").Children(0).Clicik
myDoc.parentWindow.execScript "$('#s2id_beanCounter').trigger('onclick')"
```

It would be a tremendous help if you could lead me to an answer as how can I put a valid input into this box or at least how to click the box to make the drop down list appear.

Edited 06-20-2017

Using advice from @dee I was able to get the last name into the searchable input elelment and it drops down all of the people with that last name.  As you can see from the html code below the first name in the drop down box is highlighted.

When I hover the mouse over any of the names, the name under the mouse becomes the highlighted name.  And of course a left click of the mouse enters that name into the input box.

How can I automate the process of highlighting the name we need form the UL list and click it to put into the input box as a valid value?

The one caveat about this search is that it only searches the last name.

```
<div class="select2-drop select2-display-none bigdrop select2-with-searchbox select2-drop-active" id="select2-drop" style="left: 1049.13px; top: 227.83px; width: 238px; display: block;">   
  <div class="select2-search">       
      <input class="select2-input" spellcheck="false" type="text" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off">   
 </div>   

  <ul class="select2-results">
      <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted">
          <div class="select2-result-label">
              <div>JOSEPH MENGELA (ARGENTINA)</div></div>
      </li>

      <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
          <div class="select2-result-label">
              <div>TOMMY MENGELA (ITALY)</div>
          </div>
      </li>

      <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
          <div class="select2-result-label">
              <div>SUSAN H MENGELA (POLAND)</div>
          </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the code I used to get the dropdown box to show all the names of people in our system with that last name.

```
Set myElement = myDoc.getElementById("s2id_IDofInputBoxHere").Children(0)
SendMouseDownEvent myDoc, myElement
Set myElement = myDoc.getElementById("select2-drop").Children(0).Children(0)
myDoc.getElementById("select2-drop").Children(0).Children(0).Value = "mengela"
' Send input event to trigger searching of text 'BR"
Dim kev
Set kev = myDoc.createEvent("KeyboardEvent")
kev.initEvent "input", True, False
myElement.dispatchEvent kev
```

Comment: have you tried to get it from the class name?  also `.fireevent` also `clicik`?

Comment: No, not yet.  But we will now!  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For Version 4.0.3 of select 2

*Solution 1*

In `select2.js` there is function:

```
this.$selection.on('mousedown', function (evt) {
  // Only respond to left clicks
  if (evt.which !== 1) {
    return;
  }

  self.trigger('toggle', {
    originalEvent: evt
  });
});
```

This function handles the `mousedown` event of the `selection` so first I have tried to send `mousedown` to the `selection` so we get the `selection` open and then to put the text into search box. Finally it is necessary to send input event to trigger searching.

```
Sub Select2Demo()

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim url As String

    url = "file:///C:/Temp/StackOverflow/html/Select2VbaDemo.html"
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate url

    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set doc = ie.document

    ' Open drop down
    Dim sp As HTMLSpanElement
    Set sp = doc.querySelector("span[class^=select2-selection]")
    SendMouseDownEvent doc, sp

    ' Put value into search box
    Dim inp
    Set inp = doc.querySelector("input[class=select2-search__field]")
    inp.Value = "BR"

    ' Send input event to trigger searching of text 'BR"
    Dim kev
    Set kev = doc.createEvent("KeyboardEvent")
    kev.initEvent "input", True, False
    inp.dispatchEvent kev

    'ie.Quit
End Sub

Private Sub SendMouseDownEvent(doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, target As IEventTarget)
    Dim mev As Object
    Dim eventType As String
    Dim canBubble As Boolean
    Dim cancelable As Boolean
    Dim viewArg As IHTMLWindow2
    Dim detailArg As Long
    Dim screenXArg As Long
    Dim screenYArg As Long
    Dim clientXArg As Long
    Dim clientYArg As Long
    Dim ctrlKeyArg As Boolean
    Dim altKeyArg As Boolean
    Dim shiftKeyArg As Boolean
    Dim metaKeyArg As Boolean
    Dim buttonArg As Object ' Unsupported Variant-Type
    Dim relatedTargetArg As IEventTarget

    Set mev = doc.createEvent("MouseEvent")
    eventType = "mousedown"
    canBubble = True
    cancelable = False
    Set viewArg = doc.parentWindow
    Set relatedTargetArg = target

    mev.initMouseEvent eventType, canBubble, cancelable, viewArg, _
        detailArg, screenXArg, screenYArg, clientXArg, clientYArg, _
        ctrlKeyArg, altKeyArg, shiftKeyArg, metaKeyArg, buttonArg, _
        relatedTargetArg
    target.dispatchEvent mev
End Sub
```

---

*Solution 2*

Other idea would be to put `focus` to the `selection` and simply send `{ENTER}` which is the same as when the user opens the `selection`.
We need the `selection` to be opened because then the `input` will be added to the DOM (otherwise it is not there). The following code worked for me.

Notice the `SetFocusIE` which ensures that the `IE-Window` is active one and so the `SendKeys` will target the right window. HTH.

```
Option Explicit

' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Private Declare Function SetFocusIE Lib "user32" Alias "SetFocus" _ 
    (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Sub Select2Demo2()

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim url As String

    url = "file:///C:/Temp/StackOverflow/html/Select2VbaDemo.html"
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate url

    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set doc = ie.document

    Dim sp As HTMLSpanElement
    Set sp = doc.querySelector("span[class^=select2-selection]")

    sp.Click ' Selection gets focus
    SetFocusIE ie.hwnd ' IE gets active window
    SendKeys "~", True ' Sends ENTER: Selection opens

    ' put value to search box then 
    Dim inp
    Set inp = doc.querySelector("input[class=select2-search__field]")
    inp.Value = "BR"

    ie.Quit
End Sub
```

---

> Sample page used

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.js"></script>
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#s2id_beanCounter").select2();     
        });
    </script>

    <div class="s2-example" >           
        <label class="control-label" for="s2id_beanCounter">
            Enter Employee Name
            <select class="js-example-basic-single js-states form-control" id="s2id_beanCounter" style="width:100%">
                  <option value="JD">John Doe</option>
                  <option value="BL">Bruce Lee</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

> Result im IE

[image]

> EDIT: For Version 3.4.1 of select2

In version 3.4.1 it looks different. There is this function resposible for selecting the highlighted element:

```
this.dropdown.on("mouseup", resultsSelector, this.bind(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(".select2-result-selectable").length > 0) {
        this.highlightUnderEvent(e);
        this.selectHighlighted(e);
    }
}));
```

So the following code can be used to highlight and select one of the filtered elements. HTH

```
Option Explicit

' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Sub Select2DemoVersion341()

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim url As String

    url = "file:///C:/Temp/StackOverflow/html/select2demo/Select2VbaDemo.html"
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate url

    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set doc = ie.document

    ' Get reference to target serach input box before select2 starts to mess up with the DOM when the select opens
    Dim inp As HTMLInputElement
    Set inp = doc.querySelector("div[class^=select2-container] input[class=select2-input]")

    ' Open drop down
    Dim select2Choice As HTMLAnchorElement
    Set select2Choice = doc.querySelector("a[class^=select2-choice]")
    SendMouseEvent doc, select2Choice, "mousedown"

    ' Put value into search box
    inp.Value = "mengela"

    ' Send input event to trigger searching of text 'mengela"
    Dim kev
    Set kev = doc.createEvent("KeyboardEvent")
    kev.initEvent "input", True, False
    inp.dispatchEvent kev

     ' Get the search results
    Dim selectResultUl As HTMLUListElement
    Set selectResultUl = doc.querySelector("ul[class=select2-results]")
    If selectResultUl.Children.Length = 1 Then
        ' Verify 'No results found' posibility
        If selectResultUl.Children(0).className = "select2-no-results" Then
            MsgBox "No results"
            ie.Quit
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    ' Deselect currently selected item by removing select2-highlighted class
    Dim selectedResultsLis As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim selectResultsLi As HTMLLIElement
    Set selectedResultsLis = selectResultUl.getElementsByTagName("li")
    For Each selectResultsLi In selectedResultsLis
        If selectResultsLi.className Like "*select2-highlighted*" Then
            selectResultsLi.className = VBA.Strings.Replace(selectResultsLi.className, "select2-highlighted", "")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next selectResultsLi

    ' Select another li-element, e.g. last one by adding select2-highlighted class
    Dim newSelectionLi As HTMLLIElement
    Set newSelectionLi = selectedResultsLis(selectedResultsLis.Length - 1)
    newSelectionLi.className = newSelectionLi.className & " select2-highlighted"

    ' Send mouseup to result label to select the highligted element
    Dim resultLabel As HTMLDivElement
    Set resultLabel = newSelectionLi.getElementsByClassName("select2-result-label")(0)
    SendMouseEvent doc, resultLabel, "mouseup"

    'ie.Quit
End Sub

Private Sub SendMouseEvent(doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, target As IEventTarget, eventTypeVal)
    Dim mev As Object
    Dim eventType As String
    Dim canBubble As Boolean
    Dim cancelable As Boolean
    Dim viewArg As IHTMLWindow2
    Dim detailArg As Long
    Dim screenXArg As Long
    Dim screenYArg As Long
    Dim clientXArg As Long
    Dim clientYArg As Long
    Dim ctrlKeyArg As Boolean
    Dim altKeyArg As Boolean
    Dim shiftKeyArg As Boolean
    Dim metaKeyArg As Boolean
    Dim buttonArg As Object ' Unsupported Variant-Type
    Dim relatedTargetArg As IEventTarget

    Set mev = doc.createEvent("MouseEvent")
    eventType = eventTypeVal
    canBubble = True
    cancelable = False
    Set viewArg = doc.parentWindow
    Set relatedTargetArg = target

    mev.initMouseEvent eventType, canBubble, cancelable, viewArg, _
        detailArg, screenXArg, screenYArg, clientXArg, clientYArg, _
        ctrlKeyArg, altKeyArg, shiftKeyArg, metaKeyArg, buttonArg, _
        relatedTargetArg
    target.dispatchEvent mev
End Sub
```

Demo page with select2.js/css of version 3.4.1 can be downloaded from my [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/630efk5cky3wejb/select2demo.zip?dl=0)  as zip file.

Comment: Thank you.  I think your first solution might be helpful because it will allow me to trigger the dropdown.  My problem on this is that this is an "<input" box and does not have an associated "<select" box.  Through trial and error I've discovered that the select boxes on our website can be changed with the command similar to myDoc.parentWindow.execScript "$('#s2id_beanCounter').val('Bruce Lee').trigger('change')".

Comment: That will change the select box without the need for the drop down box at all, the caveat being your value must be an exact match of one of the list items, or in other words valid.  But this input box is much trickier and I think we'll have to use the logic of your first suggestion to handle it.  Thanks!  I'll let you know how it comes out.

Comment: so far your advice (part 1) has got me started very well.  Now I'm trying to select a name from the list of names that comes down in the drop down list.  In your example there was only one person named "Bruce" - and your code selects his name perfectly.  But if there are several people with the same last name I need to select the correct one.  I've added the coder to my question above.  Would you please look at it and possibly advise me?

Comment: @JohnMuggins could you tell, which version of `select2` are you using? The html produced in my demo page looks different. Maybe I am using different version then you. I am using version `Select2 4.0.3`. So please have a look into the file `select2.js` at the very top there is the version.

Comment: It has a css file in this directory: select2-3.4.1.  Again, this is an input box.  All of the other search boxes are select boxes and can be triggered with execscript, but this one they chose to use an input box.  I think because the data list is very large, probably 20,000 or more names.  This is our company's new software and again they made it horrible for the workers to engage with.  It's a 2 min process that now takes 10.

Comment: I think I need to use some sort of mouseevent to choose, but haven't been successful.

Comment: @JohnMuggins the information about the version of `select2` should be the first thing I had to ask :). See edit for the version `3.4.1`. In this version the `select2` attaches to  `mouseup` event of the `select2-result-label` element. This post is probably my longest one here on SO :). HTH

Comment: totally correct @dee!  You hit it right on the nail head.  Thank you so much.  I'm putting the final working code below for anyone else who might need it in the future, but you deserve the credit.  And for the record this is the best guidance I've had.

Comment: @JohnMuggins yes it was fun, I like jQuery! If the answer solved your problem, can you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

This code was derived with the help of Dee above, so if you find it useful please give him a tic up.  Select2 is an addon helper for select boxes, but in this case it used an "input" box so finding a way to select from a dropdown list is a bit different than for the selectboxes.  You might need to adjust the 'children' elements to suit you specific needs.  Here it was trial and error to find the correct elements because they had neither names or id's.

```
Sub open_EMPLOYEE_name_box_1()

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, _
        i As Long, objShell, objAllWindows, ow, myElement As IEventTarget, _
        myArray1() As String, tempNumb As Integer, myDoc As HTMLDocument, kev

    i = 2:    tempNumb = 1:    ReDim myArray1(1 To 1):
    ReDim myArray1(1 To 1):    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objAllWindows = objShell.Windows

    For Each ow In objAllWindows
        If (InStr(1, ow, "Internet Explorer", vbTextCompare)) Then
            If ow.document.Title = "Company Name : Company Page" Then
                Set ie = ow
                Set myDoc = ie.document
                GoTo mainProg
            End If
            tempNumb = tempNumb + 1
            If Not ow.document.Title = "" Then
                ReDim Preserve myArray1(1 To tempNumb)
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

mainProg:
'/////////////////////  THIS BRINGS UP THE SMITH LIST
  Set myElement = myDoc.getElementById("s2id_employeeName").Children(0)
  SendMouseDownEvent myDoc, myElement
    Set myElement = myDoc.getElementById("s2id_employeeName").Children(0)
    Set myElement = myDoc.getElementById("select2-drop").Children(0).Children(0)
    myElement.Value = "Smith"
    Set kev = myDoc.createEvent("KeyboardEvent")
    kev.initEvent "input", True, False
    myElement.dispatchEvent kev

'/////////////////////////// THIS SELECTS "STEVEN R BISHOP (HEBRON)"
Application.Wait Now + #12:00:03 AM#    '   3 second wait for dropdown box to finish
Set myClassResults = myDoc.getElementsByClassName("select2-result-label")
For Each cl In myClassResults
    If cl.innerText = "STEVEN R SMITH (CARMEL)" Then
        Set myElement = cl
        SendMouseUpEvent myDoc, myElement
    End If
Next



endItAll:
Set myClassResults = Nothing
Set myElement = Nothing
Set objAllWindows = Nothing
Set myDoc = Nothing
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub SendMouseDownEvent(doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, target As IEventTarget)
    Dim mev As Object
    Dim eventType As String
    Dim canBubble As Boolean
    Dim cancelable As Boolean
    Dim viewArg As IHTMLWindow2
    Dim detailArg As Long
    Dim screenXArg As Long
    Dim screenYArg As Long
    Dim clientXArg As Long
    Dim clientYArg As Long
    Dim ctrlKeyArg As Boolean
    Dim altKeyArg As Boolean
    Dim shiftKeyArg As Boolean
    Dim metaKeyArg As Boolean
    Dim buttonArg As Object ' Unsupported Variant-Type
    Dim relatedTargetArg As IEventTarget
        Dim kev

    Set mev = doc.createEvent("MouseEvent")
    eventType = "mousedown"
    canBubble = True
    cancelable = False
    Set viewArg = doc.parentWindow
    Set relatedTargetArg = target

    mev.initMouseEvent eventType, canBubble, cancelable, viewArg, _
        detailArg, screenXArg, screenYArg, clientXArg, clientYArg, _
        ctrlKeyArg, altKeyArg, shiftKeyArg, metaKeyArg, buttonArg, _
        relatedTargetArg
    target.dispatchEvent mev
End Sub

Private Sub SendMouseUpEvent(doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, target As IEventTarget)
    Dim mev As Object
    Dim eventType As String
    Dim canBubble As Boolean
    Dim cancelable As Boolean
    Dim viewArg As IHTMLWindow2
    Dim detailArg As Long
    Dim screenXArg As Long
    Dim screenYArg As Long
    Dim clientXArg As Long
    Dim clientYArg As Long
    Dim ctrlKeyArg As Boolean
    Dim altKeyArg As Boolean
    Dim shiftKeyArg As Boolean
    Dim metaKeyArg As Boolean
    Dim buttonArg As Object ' Unsupported Variant-Type
    Dim relatedTargetArg As IEventTarget
        Dim kev

    Set mev = doc.createEvent("MouseEvent")
    eventType = "mouseup"
    canBubble = True
    cancelable = False
    Set viewArg = doc.parentWindow
    Set relatedTargetArg = target

    mev.initMouseEvent eventType, canBubble, cancelable, viewArg, _
        detailArg, screenXArg, screenYArg, clientXArg, clientYArg, _
        ctrlKeyArg, altKeyArg, shiftKeyArg, metaKeyArg, buttonArg, _
        relatedTargetArg
    target.dispatchEvent mev
End Sub
```