# How to click a combobox on a website using VBA

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I think it's imperative to mention first that I have zero to no experience working with HTML. That being said I have been trying to piece together information that I have found on the internet but nothing seems to be helping.

The problem:

I am trying to click on a Combobox on a given website.

[image: comboxbox]

I know the combobox is embedded in the HTML as such:

```html
<body id="bodyTag" class="mo-brand-lumina"
 <form method="post" id="form1"
  <div id="main-container"
   <div class="main-content"
    <div id="data-manager"
     <div id="data-definition-select-container"
      <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container --default valid select2-container --below select2-container --focus
       <span class="selection"
        <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single role="combobox" aria-expanded="false"
```

Important observation: when clicking the dropdown the `--focus` changes to `--open`, and the `aria-expanded` changes to `true`.

Now, my attempt(s). I have created the `oIE` object, logged into the webpage okay but can't seem to click the combobox. This is clearly due to lack of understanding. Below is my VBA, with all my attempts at clicking the button. I have tried using `.GetElementsByClassName`, `.getElementById`, `.Elements` and `.getElementsByName`. Obviously incorrectly (due to me not understanding!).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub OpenWebPage()

    Dim oIE As Object
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim HTML As HTMLDocument, hDataManager As IHTMLElementCollection, hDropSelect

    Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'//---Open the browser and log in, then navigate to the data manager
    sURL = "https://publicisuk.demo.lumina.mediaocean.com/Admin/DataManager.aspx"

    oIE.Silent = True 'No pop-ups
    oIE.Visible = True
    oIE.Navigate sURL

    'wait for process to complete before executing the next task
    Do While oIE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until oIE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    oIE.Document.Forms(0).All("LoginUsername").Value = "myUsername"
    oIE.Document.Forms(0).All("LoginPassword").Value = "myPassword"
    oIE.Document.Forms(0).Submit

    'wait for process to complete before executing the next task
    Do While oIE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until oIE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

'//---Start with vendor
    Set HTML = oIE.Document

'    Set hDataManager = HTML.getElementById("data-manager")
'    Set hDropSelect = hDataManager.getElementByClassName("select2-selection select2-selection--single")
    Set hDropSelect = HTML.getElementsByClassName("select2-selection select2-selection--single")

    hDropSelect.Elements("aria-expanded").Value = "true"


'    oIE.Document.getElementById("select2-DataDefinitionAutoComplete-container").Click

'    oIE.Document.Forms(0).All("DataDefinitionAutoComplete").Click

'    oIE.Documents.Forms("data-manager").Elements("data-detail-container").Value = "Vendor"
'    oIE.Document.getElementsByName("SubscribeButton")(0).Click



    Set oIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

After I click the below is displayed:

[image: dropdown]

Any guidance on the above would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to click on a Combobox? Could you please describe the background and what is the task you trying to accomplish in general?

Comment: @omegastripes Sure. I need to click on the combobox to then input "Vendor" which will show the current vendors in the database. I then need to export this in Excel format which I will then use to pull information from. I have already assessed using PowerQuery to build a data connection but this does not work. The company doesn't offer an API to their database either, so a front end web scraper was my solution.

Comment: The problem is that others can't reproduce the issue due to registration needed. I would suggest you to opt to HTTP requests instead of IE.

Comment: What is the html of the acutal down arrow on the combobox?

Comment: Hi @QHarr here is the HTML for the actual arrow: `<span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>`, however not sure if important to note, that the user is not required to click the arrow, but they can also click the body of the box to open the dropdown. Also something to note, I have resorted to using `Application.SendKeys` method (horrible I know), so if you can assist that'll be great, but if not I have a workaround.

Comment: By default, we are using Html select tag to display the selected items, please check your code, whether you are using the select tag or not? If not, please check the details html element about the combo box, how do you display the items?

Comment: Have a look at the discussion here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44545772/filling-html-input-boxes-that-were-created-with-select2. It looks that page is using a `Select2` control from jQuery. You might be able to get away with something like `myDoc.parentWindow.execScript "$('MyCssSelectorForSelectListGoesHere').val('TheValueIWantToSet').trigger('change')"` or `"$('MyCssSelectorForSelectListGoesHere').val('TheValueIWantToSet').change()`"

Comment: I think I asked before but is there a way to create a test account?

Comment: The combobox you are trying to click on seems to be a Kendo Grid. Giving [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43127317/selecting-actioning-items-in-kendo-ui-widgets-using-excel-vba) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927414/unable-to-perform-a-click-on-a-certain-link) a go will lead you to the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the inability to reproduce the example above in detail, I can understand the lack of response.

I managed to find a workable solution using a combination of `.Focus`, `.innerText` and `.SendKeys` to get the desired result, although, the `.SendKeys` is by no means the best way.

I used:

```vb
With oIE.document
    'set focus
    .getElementsByClassName("select2-selection__rendered")(0).Focus
    'send enter to trigger dropdown
    Application.SendKeys "~", True

    'now get dropdown box
    .getElementsByClassName("select2-search__field")(0).innerText = "Vendor"
    'send trigger
    Application.SendKeys "~", True

    'subscribe button - this works
'   With .querySelector("#SubscribeButton")
'       .Click
'   End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

In a previous problem I found that calling the focus method on the control is question is necessary to effect a click.  So calling

```
hDropSelect.Elements("aria-expanded").focus
```

before

```
hDropSelect.Elements("aria-expanded").Value = "true"
```

might help.