# Select an option from combo box on webpage with vba'

Tags: html, vba, webautomation

I'm developing a macro to automate work item creations in VBA using Internet explorer ,
I Need to automate selecting an options "customer " from combo box drop down , since the options are in list and the script is a bit confusing could you please help me with the correct VB command to select the "Customer" option.

I have tried the following nothing seems to work

```
'.getElementById("com_ibm_team_workitem_web_mvvm_view_queryable_combo_QueryableSection_QueryableElement_323").Select
   ' .getElementsByClassName("ValueHolder ViewBorder")("SectionElementImage sprite-image-40").Select
   ' .getElementsByClassName("ValueLabelHolder")(2).selectelement.DropDowns("SectionElementImage sprite-image-42").Value
    '.selectElement.DropDowns("DropDown1").Value
    '.getElementByClassid("ValueHolder ViewBorder").selectedIndex = 1
    '.getElementsByClassid("com_ibm_team_workitem_web_mvvm_view_queryable_combo_QueryableSection_QueryableElement_359").Value
    '.SendKeys ("{Enter}"
```

[HTML code and website  image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdr39.png)

Comment: this is related but I am unable to identify the correct tag to use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57037741/how-to-click-a-combobox-on-a-website-using-vba

Comment: This is not an option element so instead it may be that you need to click on it. You can use css selectors and relationships between elements/attributes to target.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try something like this

```
ie.Document.getElementById("ComboBox").selectedIndex = 2
```

Being selectedIndex your 1,2,3 index of the combobox.